# JSONDecodeError at Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, django

I have tried using the methods with recent answers from this platform but am still getting this error. I am reading my data from the database to update my cart. When i click on the up button it just works okay, whenever i click on the remove button(down error i get

```
File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\UmojaWater\products\views.py", line 177, in updateItem
productId = data['productId']
```

KeyError: 'productId'
[20/Aug/2021 05:56:55] "POST /update/ HTTP/1.1" 500 64093

When i check teh json file on browser it brings the jsonencoding type. In general, the encoding is teh one causing all these problems. I can append the number of products but i cannot decrese them. How can i fix this.
Here is my view.py code

```
def AllProducts(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartitems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {' get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0}
        cartitems = order['get_cart_items']

    allproducts = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'allproducts': allproducts,  'cartitems': cartitems}
    return render(request, "products/AllProducts.html", context)


@login_required
def userCart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartitems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {' get_cart_total': 0, 'get_cart_items': 0}
        cartitems = order['get_cart_items']
    context = {'items': items, 'order': order, 'cartitems': cartitems}
    return render(request, 'products/cart.html', context)

def updateItem(request):

    # requests.models.PreparedRequest.prepare_headers
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
        customer=customer)

    orderitem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantity+1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderitem.quantity = (orderitem.quantity-1)
        print("Removed")
    orderitem.save()

    if orderitem.quantity <= 0:
        orderitem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('It was added', safe=False)

The below code is foy my ajax js
ar updateBtns=document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart")

for(i=0; i< updateBtns.length;i++){
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId=this.dataset.product
        var action=this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Acton:',action)

        console.log('USER', user)
        if(user=='AnonymousUser'){
            console.log('User is not authenticated')
        }
        else{
           updateUserOrder(productId, action)
        }


     
    })
}
   function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
            var url='update/'

            fetch(url , {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action':action})

            })
               .then((response) => {
                   return response.json()
               })
               .then((data) => {
                   console.log('data',data)
                   location.reload()
               })
               

    }
```

Here is my cart.html templates, the arrowup.jpg and arrow_down.jpg are used to increse or decrease product in my cart.

```
{% extends 'products/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{%load static%}
<style>
    .container{
        background-color: white;
    }
</style>

<div class="container mb-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th scope="col"> </th>
                            <th scope="col">Product</th>
                            <th scope="col">Available</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Quantity</th>
                            <th scope="col" class="text-right">Price</th>
                            <th> </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="cartItems">
                        {%for item in items%}
                        <tr class="cart-items">
                            <td><img src="{{item.product.image.url}}" height="100px" width="100px"/> </td>
                            <td class="title">{{item.product.title}}</td>
                            <td>In stock</td>
                            <td>
                                <p class="quantity">{{item.quantity}}</p>
                                <div class="quantity">
                                    <img data-product={{item.product.id}} data-action="add" class="chg-quantity update-cart" src="{% static 'images/arrow_up.jpg' " alt="P">

                                    <img data=product-{{item.product.id}} data-action="remove" class="chg-quantity update-cart"
                                        src="{% static 'images/arrow_downjfif' " alt="d">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><input class="form-control cart-quantity-input" type="text" value="{{item.quantity}}" /></td>
                            <td class="text-right">Ksh.{{item.product.price}}</td>
                            <td class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  id="danger-buttons"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                </button> </td>
                        </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                        
                        <tr >
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Items</td>
                            <td class="text-right">{{order.get_cart_items}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Shipping</td>
                            <td class="text-right">6,90 €</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                            <td class="text-right"><strong>Ksh.{{order.get_cart_totals}}</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-block btn-light" href="{%url 'waters' %}">Continue Shopping</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-right">
                      
                    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success text-uppercas" href="{%url 'checkout'%}">Checkout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

                <script>
                    
            
                </script>
  
<!-- Footer -->
{% endblock content %}
```

I want the up and down button to work right
[image]

Comment: `json.loads(request.body)` is causing the error. Did you mean to use `request.POST`?

Comment: Not the json.loads(request.body) to fetch data and send the to cart...If i use the request.POST it brings another error the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not QueryDict

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help but try this one.
Replace this code: cartitems = order['get_cart_items']
with: cartitems = order['get_cart_items')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Use an open square bracket and a close round bracket? **cartitems = order['get_cart_items')**